# How to drop duplicates where there is no data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, duplicates

I Have a df that looks like this:

```
Id   column2   column3  column4   column5
1            1         1        1        nan
1            1         nan      nan      1
```

I want to drop duplicates via the `Id` column and keep data in columns where the `Id` has data, how do i do this?

new df:

```
 Id   column2   column3  column4   column5
1         1         1        1        1
```

currently I am using these lines of code with no success in keeping rows with data:

```
1.  df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='Id',keep='last')

2.  df = df.loc[df.notnull().sum(1).groupby(analysis.Id).idxmax()]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) for return last not NaNs values per groups:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Id', as_index=False).last()
print (df1)
   Id  column2  column3  column4  column5
0   1        1      1.0      1.0      1.0    df1 = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).last()
```